# My datagrip fails to load my postgres while downloading driver. How do I solve this?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

Hi I'm trying to run postgres locally so that I could read the local postgres from
datagrip.

However, when I add postgres into my datagrip I ran into this problem.
[image]

So I tried to download driver files (I was expecting it would solve this problem)
Then it shows this.
[image]

I was stuck here and tried to figure out but I couldn't.

What should I do to solve this issue?

The last stage I was stuck is one step after when I hit 'set up http'
[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Do you have proper internet connection I hope?

Comment: DataGrip couldn’t download the driver, and details should have been recorded in idea.log. See where to find it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrip couldn’t download the driver, and details should have been recorded in idea.log. See where to find it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run DataGrip as Administrator.

Then you should be able to download the driver. When the download succeeded you can close DataGrip, open DataGrip again (this time not as administrator) and connect to the PostgreSQL database.

I hope it works.